# Gaussian profile-plane wave

Tags: waves

Simple question:
How does the following wave look like?
$$
U(x,y,z,t) = U_0e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}}e^{ikz}e^{-i\omega t}
$$
Is it a plane wave? How does this propagate in space? What is the wavenumber vector($\vec{k}$)? Do the spatial frequencies $k_x,k_y$ of the gaussian profile contribute to $\vec{k}$?

Comment: This is not even an exact solution of the wave equation, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (sigma)^2 is >>wavelength, then is is a superposition of several plane waves.  Essentially the spatial frequency spectrum is the fourier transform of the gaussian term.  So, the spectrum would be centered at "k," but with a width ~sigma.

The smaller sigma, the larger the spread in wave vectors.  Similarly if sigma were very large, such that the amplitude of U were nearly uniform, then the range of wave vectors will be small, and very nearly a single plane wave.

Comment: Per values of $z$, what does it look like?

Comment: It doesn't matter how large one makes $\sigma$, the wave packet will always spread out, so even in approximation it's only good in a small volume. I have a hunch that it's actually only a good approximation for a volume smaller than $\sigma$, which kind of defeats the purpose somewhat. At the very least one should model the phase modulation as a function of cylinder radius, I think.